# FirebaseAuthUI not adding new Facebook user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've been experimenting with the new iOS FirebaseUI Authentication (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseUI) and set up a very simple Swift app for signing in with Google, Email/pw, and Facebook.

The Google and Email/PW sign in work just fine - creates a new user in the database, but I'm having trouble with new Facebook users. I go through the process of authenticating the app (and it then shows up as an allowed App on my facebook account) but the new user is never created in the Authentication user database.

I've added the FacebookAppID in the Info.plist, made sure the oAuth redirect URIs were added to the facebook app login settings - not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Here's the code for the single view controller with Sign-in button:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var signinButton: UIButton!      
    var user: FIRUser?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func signIn() {
        let authUI = FIRAuthUI.authUI()!
        let googleAuthUI = FIRGoogleAuthUI.init(clientID:FIRApp.defaultApp()!.options.clientID)
        let facebookAuthUI = FIRFacebookAuthUI.init(appID: NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["FacebookAppID"] as! String)

        authUI.signInProviders = [googleAuthUI!, facebookAuthUI!]

        let authViewController = FIRAuthUI.authUI()!.authViewController()

        self.presentViewController(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func signOut() {
        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the error for this! At some point I had switched on the "Is App Secret embedded in the client?" setting within advanced settings of the facebook app. Switching that off solved the issue.
[Advanced settings toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxxbv.png)

Comment: Thank you! Not obvious at all.